# Connecting to a NAS

Tags: macos, nas

I'm trying to set up a new NAS. I'm using an old DNR-326 with 2 4TB drives.

I have formated them as Standard RAID type. And that is how far I can go from the NAS management frontend.

So, when I try to connect to the drives, using smb://192.168.1.157 I get the following message:

```
There was a problem connecting to the server “192.168.1.157”. 
The share does not exist on the server. Please check the share name, and then try again.
```

I don't know what else I can do.

Ideas?

Comment: If you are unable to create a share on the NAS using the management app or the NAS web console, I am afraid you are out of luck. For **ANY** NAS to work you have to create at least one share (shared folder) and then tell the NAS *how* to share the folder, EG SMB, NFS, Appleshare, etc. And then set the permissions, without those basics all you have is two drives in an enclosure eating up electricity.

Comment: Is your DNR-326 this https://www.thegeekpub.com/5899/review-d-link-dnr-326-nvr/ which is a network video recorder (NVR), not a NAS.